# Playing mp4 files in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, video, razor-pages

###### I'm trying to play `mp4` video in razor page using resources below:

- [Displaying Video in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/10-working-with-video)
- [How to Play Video in ASP.NET CORE Using HTML 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abIa1U5IN8U)
- [Play (Live Stream) Video Files (MP4) using HTML5 Video Player in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Play-Live-Stream-Video-Files-MP4-using-HTML5-Video-Player-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)
- [How To Dynamically Upload And Play Video File Using ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-dynamically-upload-and-play-video-file-using-asp-net-mvc-5/)
- [HTML Video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Unluckily none of them worked for me.

###### Currently I have one `mp4` file in `root/Videos/one.mp4` and this is how my `root/Program.cs` looks like:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

###### This is what I already tried in `root/Pages/Index.cshtml` using following examples.

```html
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Embedded Video Example</h1>
    <p>The following video provides an introduction to WebMatrix:</p>

    <!-- example 1 -->
    <video id="VideoPlayer" src="~/Videos/one.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls="true"
        width="400" height="350" loop="true"/>

    <!-- example 2 -->
    <video id="VideoPlayer" src=@Url.Content("~/Videos/one.mp4")" type="video/mp4" controls="true"
        width="400" height="350" loop="true"/>

    <!-- example 3 -->
    <video id="VideoPlayer" controls="true" width="400" height="350">
        <source src="~/Videos/one.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <!-- example 4 -->
     <video id="VideoPlayer" controls="true" width="400" height="350">
        <source src="@Url.Content("~/Videos/one.mp4")" type="video/mp4">
    </video> 

    <!-- example 5 -->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="~/Videos/one.mp4" frameborder="0" type="video/mp4"
        allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <!-- example 6 -->
    <iframe width="560" 
                height="315"
                type="video/mp4"
                src="@Url.Content("~/Videos/one.mp4")" 
                frameborder="0" 
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

My `net --version` is `6.0.100`

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Shouldn't all your static assets be in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: For testing purposes I put in Videos instead of wwwroot.

Comment: Ok, but `~` resolves to the wwwroot folder. That's what `app.UseStaticFiles();` does. `root/...` won't work.

Comment: Could be the video encoding, check the [HTML5 video - Browser support (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support). MP4 is just a container (like MKV or AVI), the browser must also support the video codec.

Comment: Also, hitting F12 and checking if everything seems fine (no 404) could be useful

Comment: Move your Videos folder to wwwroot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [gunr2171's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171) comment. Solution below:

###### Instead of keeping `one.mp4` file in:

`root/Videos/one.mp4`

###### Move it to:

`root/wwwroot/Videos/one.mp4`

###### and then use in `cshtml`:

```html
<video id="VideoPlayer" src="~/videos/one.mp4" controls width="450" height="450" loop />
```